# How to remove null values from JSON response

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

We are using Jmeter tool.

The below JSON response we are getting for a request and we need to pass the non-`null` values to next request. Please suggest.

```
{
    "amount": null,
    "biller": null,
    "billerCategory": null,
    "billerList": null,
    "billerLocation": null,
    "billerLocationList": null,
    "billerNameList": null,
    "blPinValidate": null,
    "category": "Special Tariff Voucher",
    "category_LIST": null,
    "circle": "MaharashtraandGoa",
    "dthNumber": null,
    "isBlLiveBillFetch": false,
    "key_OPERATOR_CIRCLE": null,
    "key_PLAN": [
        "6.00 - Local Mobile calls at 1psec - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "7.00 - Local Mobile calls at 30pmin, First 120 Local seconds of the day at 2psec - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "8.00 - STD Mobile calls at 25pmin, First 120seconds of the day at 2psec - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "16.00 - Local + STD Mobile calls at 1psec - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "17.00 - Local Mobile calls at 30pmin - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "22.00 - Local Vodafone to Vodafone Mobile calls at 10pmin, First 120 Local Vodafone to Vodafone seconds of the day at 2psec - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "23.00 - Unlimited Local + STD Vodafone to Vodafone Calls and 100 MB 3G4G Data (4G Handset) 50 MB for Other Handset for 1 day. - Talktime :NA - Validity :1",
        "24.00 - Local + STD Vodafone calls at 15pmin, first 120 seconds of the day at 2psec + Rs.6 Talktime with 28 days validity - Talktime :6.00 - Validity :28",
        "25.00 - Rs.25 and 2 Local Vodafone Night Minutes - Talktime :25.00 - Validity :3",
        "27.00 - 7500 Seconds to Local Vodafone Mobile - Talktime :NA - Validity :2",
        "34.00 - STD Mobile calls at 25pmin + Rs.5 Talktime - Talktime :5.00 - Validity :28",
        "35.00 - Local + STD Mobile calls at 30pmin - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "38.00 - Local Mobile calls at 30pmin - Talktime :NA - Validity :56",
        "41.00 - Local Vodafone to Vodafone Mobile calls at 10pmin - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "42.00 - STD Mobile Calls at 25pmin - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "45.00 - Unlimited Local + STD Vodafone to Vodafone Calls and 250 MB 3G4G Data (4G Handset) 50 MB for Other Handset for 7 days. - Talktime :NA - Validity :7",
        "54.00 - Talktime of Rs.43.96 and 1 Local Vodafone Night Mins - Talktime :43.96 - Validity :NA",
        "57.00 - Local + STD Mobile calls at 30pmin + 5 Local Night Vodafone to Vodafone Minutes - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "60.00 - Get Talktime between Rs.51 and Rs.100 - Talktime :51.00 - Validity :NA",
        "65.00 - Rs.65 and 2 Local Vodafone Night Minutes - Talktime :65.00 - Validity :6",
        "69.00 - 15000 Local Vodafone to Vodafone Mobile seconds - Talktime :NA - Validity :7",
        "89.00 - Unlimited Local + STD Vodafone to Vodafone + 100min Vodafone to Other Local + STD Calls and 250 MB 3G4G Data (4G Handset) 50 MB for Other Handset for 7 days. - Talktime :NA - Validity :7",
        "91.00 - 18000 Local Vodafone to Vodafone Mobile seconds - Talktime :NA - Validity :10",
        "98.00 - 12500 Local + STD Mobile Seconds. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "103.00 - Local + STD Vodafone to Vodafone Mobile calls at 15pmin - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "106.00 - 250 MB Data + Talktime Rs.25. Special features included call 1 Local Vodafone buddy at 10pmin, option of 60 MB Data Loan, Free subscription to Saavn Pro. - Talktime :25.00 - Validity :28",
        "118.00 - Get 325 FLEX at Rs.118, Use Calls, Internet, SMS and Roaming with one recharge. How to use FLEX 1 FLEX 1 MB Internet1 SMS1min Incoming Roaming, 2 FLEX 1min LocalSTDOutgoing Roaming. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "148.00 - Unlimited Local + STD Vodafone to Vodafone Mobile Calls, Other Calls at 1psec + 300 MB Data for 4G Handsets50 MB Data for non-4G handsets, SMS at 25p FUP for Vodafone to Vodafone Calls-300 minday, 1200 minweek, Calls to 300 unique numbersweek, charge of 10pm beyond this. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "178.00 - 500 MB Data + Talktime Rs.30. Special features included call 1 Local Vodafone buddy at 10pmin, option of 60 MB Data Loan, Free subscription to Saavn Pro. - Talktime :30.00 - Validity :28",
        "194.00 - Get 700 FLEX at Rs.194, Use Calls, Internet, SMS and Roaming with one recharge. How to use FLEX 1 FLEX 1 MB Internet1 SMS1min Incoming Roaming, 2 FLEX 1min LocalSTDOutgoing Roaming. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "203.00 - 27000 Local + STD Mobile seconds - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "225.00 - 22000 Local + STD Mobile seconds - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "296.00 - Get 1200 FLEX at Rs.296, Use Calls, Internet, SMS and Roaming with one recharge. How to use FLEX 1 FLEX 1 MB Internet1 SMS1min Incoming Roaming, 2 FLEX 1min LocalSTDOutgoing Roaming. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "298.00 - 1536 MB Data + Talktime Rs.50. Special features included call 1 Local Vodafone buddy at 10pmin, option of 60 MB Data Loan, Free subscription to Saavn Pro. - Talktime :50.00 - Validity :28",
        "346.00 - Unlimited Local + STD Calling for 28 days with Daily capping of 300 Minutes per day. Additional 50 MB Data for 28 days. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "348.00 - Unlimited Local + STD Calling for 28 days with Daily capping of 300minutes per day. Additional 50 MB Data for 28 days. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "349.00 - All calls Unlimited including Landline + 1 GB 3G Data for 4G Handsets50 MB data for non-4G handsets, FUP - 300minday, 1200minweek, calls to 300 unique numbersweek, charge of 30pmin beyond this. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "398.00 - Get 1750 FLEX at Rs.398, Use Calls, Internet, SMS and Roaming with one recharge. How to use FLEX 1 FLEX 1 MB Internet1 SMS1min Incoming Roaming, 2 FLEX 1min LocalSTDOutgoing Roaming. - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "499.00 - 700 Local and STD min + 2 GB 3G Data - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "501.00 - Full Talktime 0 validity + 10 Vodafone to Vodafone Night mins - Talktime :501.00 - Validity :NA",
        "699.00 - 1000 Local and STD min + 4 GB 3G Data - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "715.00 - Talktime of Rs.618.74 + 2 Night Vodafone to Vodafone Minute for 1 day - Talktime :618.74 - Validity :28",
        "998.00 - 2000 Local and STD min + 6 GB 3G Data - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "1001.00 - Full Talktime, 0 validity + 10 Vodafone Night mins - Talktime :1001.00 - Validity :NA",
        "1098.00 - 3 GB 3G + Unlimited Local Vodafone to Vodafone Calls - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "1299.00 - 3000 Local and STD min + 8 GB 3G Data - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "1749.00 - 5 GB 3G + Unlimited Local Calls - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "2249.00 - 7 GB 3G + Unlimited Local and STD Calls - Talktime :NA - Validity :28",
        "3249.00 - 15 GB 3G + Unlimited Local and STD Calls + Free Incoming on Roaming at Rs.3249 - Talktime :NA - Validity :28"
    ],
    "location": null,
    "mobileNo": "9778697852",
    "objBusBillPaymentBean": null,
    "objBusTransferBean": null,
    "operator": "VODAFONE PREPAID",
    "plan": null,
    "rechargeMobileNo": "9637115216",
    "rechargeType": "MOBILE_RECHARGE",
    "ref1": null,
    "ref2": null,
    "ref3": null,
    "ref4": null,
    "ref5": null,
    "responseMessage": null,
    "stCurBal": null,
    "stRandNum": null,
    "stUserType": null,
    "stValue1": null,
    "stValue2": null,
    "stValue3": null,
    "stValue4": null,
    "stValue5": null,
    "wpin": null
}
```

Comment: .. And we want a question that is [formatted](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) correctly.

Comment: When you say you want to remove them from the response, do you mean you create this Json and would like to send only the non-`null` values, or that you receive this and would like to sanitise the Json? In either case, which language are you using, and what have you tried? Try to include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: This JSON response we are getting for a request and we need to pass the non null values to next request. We are using it in Jmeter tool (beanshell). Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns this JSON response
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

   for (Iterator<Map.Entry> it = json.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
       Map.Entry entry = it.next();
       if (entry.getValue() == null) {
           it.remove()
       }
   }

   vars.put("data", new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. JSON data without "null" elements will be available as `${data}` JMeter Variable.

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri .but this capturing the whole response in ${data}. We want only the JSON response's not null values to be captured.